# Laravel API project how retrieve images from storage and send it to frontend

Tags: php, laravel

I am working on Laravel API project

I have `destinations` table and `destination_images` table with one-to-many relationship

When storing destination I am also receiving the images and store each image in `Storage::disk('public')` and generate random name for it and store the image name in the `destination_images` table

the store function

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'name' => 'required|string|max:100',
        'description' => 'nullable|string',
        'fileSource' => 'required'
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $errors = $validator->errors();
        return response()->json($errors);
    }

    $destination = Destination::create([
        'name' => $request->name,
        'description' => $request->description
    ]);

    foreach ($request->fileSource as $img) {
        $extension = explode('/', explode(':', substr($img, 0, strpos($img, ';')))[1])[1];
        $replace = substr($img, 0, strpos($img, ',')+1);
        $image = str_replace($replace, '', $img);
        $image = str_replace(' ', '+', $image);
        $imageName = 'destination-' . Str::random(10).'.'.$extension;
        Storage::disk('public')->put($imageName, base64_decode($image));
        DestinationImage::create([
            'destination_id' => $destination->id,
            'img' => $imageName
        ]);
    }

    return response()->json('Destination Created Successfully');
}
```

My question is how to handle the show function? Should I use the image name I am getting from the database with a link in the frontend? What is the best practice for this process?

Comment: This might depend on your use cases. A common pattern would be to have an included parameter which is used to specify the relationships of the requested resource to include in the response. It’s then the responsibility of the client to decide whether it wants the images (or any other relationships) or not.

Answer (score 0):

`Laravel` can automatically include your relationships. So when you show the `Destination` just include it. Notice i'm using model binding for the `Destination`.

```
public function show(Destianation $destination) {
    $destination->load('destinationImage'); // load the relationship.

    return $destination;
}

class DestinationImage {
    protected $appends = [
        'path',
    ];

    public function getPathAttribute()
    {
         return Storage::disk('public')->path($this->img);
    }
}
```

Now your response should look like this.

```
{
    ... // fields
    destinationImages: [{
        img: "somename.jpg",
    }];
}
```

This is not enough to show the image, Laravel storage has a method called path, to get the full path of the image. Now you need to make an Eloquent Getter and append it to the `DestinationImage` model. This will automatically add it to your response.

```
class DestinationImage {
    protected $appends = [
        'path',
    ];

    public function getPathAttribute()
    {
         return Storage::disk('public')->url($this->img);
    }
}
```

Comment: **path($this->img)** will return an absolute filesystem path which can't be used in **img** tag's **src** attribute. Instead you can use `return Storage::disk('public')->url($this->img);` to get the fully qualified **url** for the image.

Comment: Oh yh my bad meant url :)